# How to go and print directory ahead of current directory in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script and want to print the path ahead of my current location. To print the current path I wrote

```
currentDir=`pwd`
echo currentDir = $currentDir

which suppose print 
currentDir = /home/a
```

Now I want to get location of s.txt file which I know is at location

```
/home/a/c/nc8989
```

The last nc8989 in this 8989 might vary but nc remains same.
How to print this location of s.txt ?

Comment: Why `javascript`?

Comment: @SGarg. I don't quite get what you want to achieve, but to find the location of a file below your working directory, do a `find . -name s.txt`. Also, I don't understand what  it means for a _path_ to be **ahead** of some location.

Comment: Consider adding details of clarity and a sample of your code please. Also as a new member perhaps you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting further questions.

Comment: `find "$currentDir" -name 's.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a file `s.txt` in a directory `/home/a/c/nc8989`, but you are not sure of the number 8989, and you want to get `/home/a/c/nc8989` as a result.

Try:

```
dirname $(ls /home/a/c/nc*/s.txt)
```